# Tags or keywords on node - drupal 7

Tags: drupal, tags, keyword

I'm struggling to find a straight answer to this question, hoping a human bean can help because my googe-ing is getting me no where.

I have two content types 'News articles' and 'video articles'. Each of these currently has taxonomy terms, for example sake lets say they have two each, Politics & religion for news and funny & cats for videos.

What I am looking for is a way to add tags to individual nodes eg a political news article will have tags or keywords 'David Cameron, Syria, Pigs etc' Essentially highlighting what the article is about.

I would like these tags separate from the taxonomy terms. Mainy because I have used taxonomy terms to create sub headings for the content types. However, I would like a more generic tagging system which will allow me to tag a node with multiple tags.

(I intend to use this for search and filtering. Foe example if someone wants to view all the articles that are tagged with David Cameron they can. But I do not wish for David Cameron to be a sub heading under my content type of News because he could also be tagged in the video content type under funny.

Additionally, these tags or keywords should be easy to add to a node (during node creation), I should be able to add multiple tags and new tags should be as easy as adding existing tags (if I'm writing about Kanye West for the first time I would like to just type his name and a tag is added)

Does such a thing even exist?
I for see there being hundreds if not thousands of tags as I described above.
Is this what taxonomies are?
Have I used taxonomies incorrectly?
essentially I am after the wordpress version of tags (https://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/tags/) or similar to stackovdrflow's tag system

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has the ability to handle tagging out of the box. Create a new taxonomy and the taxonomy as a field to your content type. When you add the new taxonomy field, select "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)" as the widget type and you now have a free tagging taxonomy field. You can add one or more new terms comma separated. Existing terms will show up in the autocomplete. Since this is a separate taxonomy it won't affect the existing taxonomy you are using to categorize content.